# ASP.NET MVC nullable field of a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, required

I'm making a Web Page with MVC and I would like to know if it's possible to set a field as nullable, I mean, the opposite of Required, because I want it to be an optional field.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

All object types can be nullable, i.e. optional, for value types you can use either the `type?` notation or explicitly with `Nullable<type>`. If you don't provide a value to the ModelBinder for that property then it will receive NULL.

Comment: If we have a property with `?` and `[required]` both. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you omit the [Required] attribute on the optional field in the model this will have the desired effect.